# Lamp in series with an LCR series circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

Suppose a capacitor of capacitance $C$, a coil of inductance $L$, a resistor of resistance $R$ and a lamp are placed in series with an alternating voltage $V$. Now, Its frequency $f$ is varied from a low to a high value while the magnitude of $V$ is kept constant.

Why and how the brightness of the lamp varies? Capacitor tries to decrease the brightness of lamp but inductor tries to increase the brightness, right?... So, which is more dominant, capacitor or inductor?